# Trim characters from a string

Tags: c#, string, trim

I need to trim a substring from a string, if that substring exists.

Specifically, if the string is "MainGUI.exe", then I need it to become "MainGUI", by trimming ".exe" from the string.

I tried this:

```
     String line = "MainGUI.exe";
     char[] exe = {'e', 'x', 'e', '.'};
     line.TrimEnd(exe);
```

This gives me the correct answer for "MainGui.exe", but for something like "MainGUIe.exe" it doesn’t work, giving me "MainGUI" instead of "MainGUIe".

I am using C#. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `Path` static class in `System.IO` namespace, it lets you strip extensions and directories from file names easily.  You can also use it to get the extension, full path, etc.  It's a very handy class and well worth looking into.

```
var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(line);
```

Gives you "MainGui", this is, of course, assuming you want to trim any file extension or you know your file is always going to be a .exe file, if you want to only trim extensions off of .exe files, however, and leave it on others.  You can test first, either by using `String.EndsWith()` or by using the `Path.GetExtension()` method.

Answer (score 13):

I would use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension) instead of string manipulation to handle this.

```
string line = “MainGUI.exe”;
string fileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(line);
```

If you only want to strip off the extension if it's `.exe`, you can check for that as well.  The following will only strip off extensions of `.exe`, but leave all other extensions intact:

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(line).ToLower();
string fileWithoutExtension = ext == ".exe" 
                               ? Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(line) 
                               : line;
```

Comment: Note that this will strip all file extensions, not just .exe.  That may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 7):

The `Path` class has a [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you are always trimming ".exe" you can trim the last 4 characters off regardless of the rest of the string.

```
line.Substring(0, line.Length - ".exe".Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string line = "MainGUI.exe";
if (line.EndsWith(".exe"))
    line = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

As no file extension has a dot (.) within it, you are safe to use this:

```
String line = "MainGUI.exe";
line = line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf('.'));
```